# How to change value in Data Transfer Object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to assign a value in my DTO to another value in another table.  I have tried the following below but does not seem to be working.  I want to change the deleted value in the DTO.Option to the deleted value in the QuestionOptions table.  My code is below:

```
  private List<DTO.Option> MapOptions(List<DAL.QuestionOption> o)
    {
        List<DTO.Option> op = new List<DTO.Option>();

        foreach (DAL.QuestionOption opt in o)
        {
            {
                DTO.Option Option = MapOption(opt.Option);


                foreach (var i in o)
                {
                    Option.Deleted = i.isDeleted;
                }
                op.Add(Option);
            }          
        }

        return op;
    }

    private DTO.Option MapOption(DAL.Option o)
    {
        return new DTO.Option()
        {
            ID = o.ID,
            Text = o.Text,
            Value = o.Value
        };
    }
```

[image]

CODE UPDATED TO

```
     private List<DTO.Option> MapOptions(List<DAL.QuestionOption> o)
    {
        List<DTO.Option> op = new List<DTO.Option>();

        foreach (DAL.QuestionOption opt in o)
        {
            op.Add(MapOption(opt.Option));
        }

        return op;
    }

        private DTO.Option MapOption(DAL.QuestionOption o)
        {
            return new DTO.Option()
            {
                ID = o.Option.ID,
                Text = o.Option.Text,
                Value = o.Option.Value,
                Deleted = o.isDeleted

            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the `List<DAL.QuestionOption>` inside a loop of the `List<DAL.QuestionOption>`, and reassigning the `Deleted` property for every one of them. Unless I'm mistaken, that's not your intention. You'd be left with every `DTO.Option.Deleted` being equal to the `DAL.QuestionOption.isDeleted` of the last item in the list. I'm guessing `DAL.QuestionOption` looks approximately like this:

```cs
public class DAL.QuestionOption
{
    public DAL.Option Option { get; set; }
    public boolean isDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class DAL.Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If so, I would just change the `MapOption` to take in the `DAL.QuestionOption` instead of `DAL.Option`:

```cs
private DTO.Option MapOption(DAL.QuestionOption o)
{
    return new DTO.Option()
    {
        ID = o.Option.ID,
        Text = o.Option.Text,
        Value = o.Option.Value,
        Deleted = o.isDeleted
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for that, i have updated the code in the original post, what argument do you think i should give to the MapOption in the MapOptions List method?

Comment: I have answered my own question :-)